# Django - html5 range slider renders strangely

Tags: html, django

I'm using the html5 range slider on a Django form. I have multiple sliders on the form. The functionality works fine but it always renders in html with these weird little errors (see image).
[image: Screenshot of slider error with and without CSS styling] and [image: Screenshot of how it renders in code].

It seems like the problem is using template tags for the slider ID. When I remove them, the little errors go away. But of course, this means I can't save the input from the range slider to the associated field. I've also tried moving the ID into various places in the input tag but that just breaks how it renders the slider altogether. Any ideas on how I can fix this would be appreciated.

This is the template:

```
<div class="range-slider">
          {{ form.content_rating_1.errors }}
          <p>  <h6> <span class="range-slider__value">0</span></p></h6>

          <input class="custom-range" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="50" id="{{ form.content_rating_1 }}" >

        </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the "wierd little error"? Do you mean that `"` character?

Comment: What do you expect this to do? `id="{{ form.content_rating_1 }}"` `id` should be a string. But `form.content_rating_1` returns the html markup for a form element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `id_for_label` property of the form field object. That will be a string. If you use `form.content_rating_1` you will render the html markup for a full form element in the `id` attribute.

```
<div class="range-slider">
  {{ form.content_rating_1.errors }}
  <input 
    class="custom-range" 
    type="range" value="0" min="0" max="50"
    id="{{ form.content_rating_1.id_for_label }}" >
</div>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. I'm still learning (clearly) & your comment helped me realise that I was simply rendering the full form field - not actually assigning an ID. The code didn't work verbatim (the field would save as empty), I had to add a name using the field.html_name attribute. It looks like this now: 
<div class="range-slider">
  {{ form.content_rating_1.errors }}
  <input  type="range" 
name = form.content_rating_1.html_name
    class="custom-range" 
 value="0" min="0" max="50"
    id="{{ form.content_rating_1.id_for_label }}" >
</div>
Please edit answer so I can accept it